# Why is texture paint showing a different UV map

Tags: uv, texture-painting, uv-image-editor

For some reason my UV map is different between UV editing and texture painting. I'm gonna try unwrapping again to see if that fixes it, but maybe there's some checkbox somewhere I'm missing.

Pictured here is what I see in texture paint mode.

[image: UV in texture paint mode]

And this is what I see in the UV editing panel.

[image: UV in the UV editing panel]

Comment: Huh, I'll do a little digging. I also found a similar question that was asked on here over a year ago that discussed how modifiers affect what appears in the texture paint panel. I turned the modifiers (bevel and sub-d) off and it looks like that mostly fixed my issue.
Still not sure why it would be affected in this way though, and I'd like to have an adequate explanation before I post an answer.

Comment: Good investigation.

Comment: It may need to be unwrapped again (Make sure the whole mesh is selected in edit mode) & the modifiers might need to be applied before proceding to paint

Comment: UVs are for mapping images onto the geometry statically. paint mode links paint tools to the viewport and the created UV dynamically.

Comment: Select all vertices in edit mode then switch back to paint mode

Answer (score 1):

This came down to a problem between UV unwrapping and my modifier stack. All modifiers need to be applied before unwrapping, otherwise there will be glitches in the UV.

In the question above, I had a sub-d and bevel modifier being applied dynamically, and this lead to inconsistencies in the UV map. By applying both and unwrapping a second time my UV islands began to appear in texture paint.